# D3 - Distribute <text> vertically inside SVG + SVG height equal children inside it

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I'm currently trying to create a tooltip to show a lot of labels inside and here's what I got so far.

```
    const tooltipContainer = d3.select(".stackedChart").append("div")
      .attr("class", css.divBox)
      .style("opacity", 0);

    const tooltipBox = tooltipContainer.append('svg')

    dataset.forEach(set => {
      tooltipLabels.push(tooltipBox.append('text').attr('class', css.tooltipLabel))
    })
```

I'm appending multiple `<text>` inside an SVG and I'm distributing this `<text>` in a weird way.

`tooltipLabels[index].attr('y', (index * 15) + "px")`

This checks the index for each data item that I' appending and sets its Y coordinate according to it.

1. **What's the best way to actually distribute vertically a bunch of `<text>` that I'm appending to my SVG?**

---

I'm also currently facing a height problem (probably because of how I'm distributing my tooltipLabels ) and I want for my SVG's height to be equal to the complete height composed by all my `<text>` but I can't figure out how I can achieve this? Should I append `g` first and only then append mt `<text>`to it. And what's the next step from there?

2. **How can I have my SVG height equal to the group of appended  inside it?**

Comment: Have you tried to use scales? Also the way you have structured your d3 code is not according to normal practice and frankly quite unusual. Usually in d3 you do not push the tooltip box to an array. Rather you create a tooltip and can pass in data to it and then iterate over the data in an internal filter function. Is there a reason you have structured your code in the above manner?

Comment: Hi, @Coola, thanks for your comment. Frankly, this is my first contact with D3 and my first iteration with this tooltip.
I figured that it wasn't coded in a very clean way but I was going to look into it after checking the initial code with my mentor.
I felt that scales weren't for this project since I figured that they were supposed to, well, display different scales, and I just want to display my labels evenly inside my tooltip

Comment: Hi @ItzaMi, in d3js, scales are functions that transform data (i.e. `domain`) to a specific length on the svg chart (i.e. `range`). Although it is usually used for chart axis scales etc, you can use it to spread out anything depending on certain values (even colors). I recommend you check out: https://www.d3indepth.com/scales/

Comment: Thank you @Coola , I'll have to take a look at it once I deliver the first tooltip done (not perfect, of course).
I was wondering if you could check my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62130716/d3-removing-elements-div-on-update) since you seem to have a great grip of d3js