# D3 - Removing elements (div) on update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have a chart with 2 viewing options (regular data and percentages).
I also have a tooltip that shows the results for each line that I'm showing
When I switch options I want my tooltip to keep showing the info (the lines are getting drawn correctly) but instead what I'm seeing is that I'm creating several tooltip boxes for each time I switch options.

My tooltip is an `append('g')` to my main chart and I'm appending my tooltip box to this tooltip which is appended to my chart which is `chartContent`

Here's the tooltip box

```
 const tooltipContainer = d3.select(".stackedChart").append("div")
  .attr("class", css.divBox)
  .style("opacity", 0);

tooltip.append("tooltipContainer")
```

On update (aka when switching options) I'm already doing this
`chartContent.remove()`
`chartContent = chart.append('g')` (to get the new info)

Now for my `.divBox` I was trying `d3.selectAll(".divBox").remove();` but I can't seem to get it to work.
Every time I switch options I get one more `.divBox`and I can see the bottom one updating with the info but the one following the tooltip is the top one (I think, I might be wrong).

What are my steps from here? I'm extremely confused

Comment: you might want to look into `join` method on d3, updating your existing nodes, rather than appending, could you setup a reproducible snippet here?

Comment: Hi, @cal_br_mar , thanks for the help. Sadly I'm a pretty junior developer and I'm not sure how I can split the project I'm working with properly to deliver a good enough snippet. I feel like, with the number of modules, I would just need to paste the entire project and I can't do that.
I figured that I could circumvent this first iteration by doing `remove()` on my created div (tooltipContainer) but I guess it doesn't work that way since it's not actually removing it.
I'll look into `join()` but I feel that it's a bit above me

Comment: Since I'm using css modules, I figured that I could just inspect my elements and see the entire code that is being reproduced for the class. It's hacky and it doesn't look good but at least it allows me to see that it's the newest appended div that is wrong and isn't displaying the data that I'm giving